# Using Sinon.js and preventing a call to my app server

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jquery-deferred, sinon

Simple enough question:

I want us sinon.js to test a piece of javascript to ensure that it calls the `$.ajax` method while doing two things:

1. I don't want to actually hit the server
2. I want to mock up a response from the server

so here's the JS:

```
  $.ajax
    url: "/tickets/id.json"
    dataType: 'json'

  .done (data) =>
    HandlebarsTemplates["tickets/popup_title"] data
```

and here's my test:

```
describe 'PopupDisplayer', ->

  beforeEach ->
    loadFixtures 'popup_displayer'
    new PopupDisplayer

    @title_stub = sinon.stub( HandlebarsTemplates, "tickets/popup_title")

    @jquery_stub = sinon.stub(jQuery, 'ajax').yieldsTo('done', {})

    //This triggers the ajax call
    $('.popupable .title').mouseenter()

  afterEach ->
    HandlebarsTemplates['tickets/popup_title'].restore()
    HandlebarsTemplates['tickets/popup_content'].restore()

    jQuery.ajax.restore()

    @server.restore()

  it 'renders the title with the data returned from the server', ->
    expect(@title_stub).toHaveBeenCalledWith( {})
```

This test failed though with the following exception:

```
TypeError: ajax expected to yield to 'done', but no object with such a property was passed. Received [[object Object]]
```

So I guess I'm wondering if I can mock up an jQuery request to get a response that can successfully respond to the `.done` call apparently I don't understand the `defferedObject()` well enough.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). Also, instead of using `<code></code>` for inline code, you should use `\`backticks\``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mock the server's response you want to stub the return value of `$.ajax`:

```cs
  ...
  @jquery_stub = sinon.stub(jQuery, 'ajax').returns
    done: (callback) -> callback {...} # your object here
  ...
```

Note that this only stubs the `done` callback. If you want to test other behaviours you will probably need to implement other handlers (`fail`, `then` etc.).

You could also return an actual jQuery Deferred object:

```cs
  ...    
  @deferred = new jQuery.Deferred
  @jquery_stub = sinon.stub(jQuery, 'ajax').returns(deferred)
  ...
```

In this case you will have to explicitly trigger the returned Deferred before doing your tests:

```cs
  ...    
  @deferred.resolveWith(null, [{}]) # your object here
  ...
```