# How can I manually trigger the success callback function that is part of a config object?

Tags: callback, call, sinon, manual

```
         Y.jsonp(
         url, {
            on: {
                success: function(res) {
                 displaySuccess();
                },
                failure: function(res) {
                } 
            },
            context: this
        });
```

I am trying to unit test the above jsonp call with different sets of data. I have tried to use `yieldTo`, but it looks like it expects "success" callback as an argument to the function. How can I trigger the success callback when it is part of a config object like above?

```
   displaySuccess = sinon.spy();
   sinon.stub(Y, "jsonp").yieldsTo("success", [1, 2, 3]); 
   //In the test call a function which calls Y.jsonp
   assert(displaySuccess.called); //Fails
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/), the correct solution would be something like (quite close to what you wrote) :

```
"test should fake successful jsonp request": function () {
    sinon.stub(Y, "jsonp").yieldsTo("success", [1, 2, 3]);
    Y.jsonp({
        on: {
            success: customSuccessHandler
        }
    });
}
```

<s>Did you also wrap that into a function for the object ("test should fake successful jsonp request") ?</s>Edit : OK, I saw your edit.

Also, try to print something in the success function, to see if it actually gets called or if the problem is elsewhere...

Maybe you have to return something (bool ?) in the function, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question. I create a spy and see if it is called in the success handler. I get the error "Unexpected error: jsonp expected to yield to 'success', but no object with such a property was passed.

Comment: Ah, maybe this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15088289/378298 (mock reply and deferred object). Also, if you put an `alert()` or a `console.log` in the callback, do you see it ?

Comment: No, it does not log in the callback.